# Correct Association Using RegularExpression

Tags: c#, regex

I have 2 classes, Topic and Settings. 
A Topic has a TopicName and a List of Settings as attributes.
A Setting has a key, a value and another list of setting as optional.

As of right now, i have a list of topics and a list of settings that i have retrieved from a Database.
I want to associate the good setting with the good (topic/setting)

Example :

```
Topic#1.TopicName = Grandpa
Setting#1.Key = Grandpa/Papa
Setting#2.Key = Grandpa/Mama
Setting#3.Key = Grandpa/Papa/Baby
```

According to my format, Topic#1 has a list of settings (Setting#1 and Setting#2)
Setting #2 contains a list of setting(Setting#3)

My code right now is

```
var topicList = new List<Topic>(); 
foreach (var topics in topicRetrieved)
{
    var topic = new Topic()
                {
                    TopicName = topics.Key,
                    Override = topics.Override,
                    Source = topics.Source,
                };

    foreach (var topicSettings in topicSettingRetrieved)
    {
        string parent = topic.TopicName + "/";
        if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(topicSettings.Key,parent))
        {
        var setting = new Setting
                        {
                        Key = topicSettings.Key,
                        Value = topicSettings.Value
                        };
        topic.SettingCollection.Add(setting);
        }
    }
    topicList.Add(topic);
    }
    return topicList.ToArray();
}
```

My problem right now is that Topic#1 will always have the list of settings 
(#1,#2 AND #3) because it contains the string "Grandpa".
I only want the Topic#1 to contain Setting#1 and Setting#2
I want to be able to add the Setting#3 to the correct place (Setting#2) 
Setting#3 = Grandpa/Papa/Baby ------ > Setting#2= Grandpa/Papa
THEN
my setting#2 will go to Topic#1
Any idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to match 'Grandpa' in all the settings, but only if it has one `/` in the setting string (as opposed to two)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `string parent = "^"+ topic.TopicName + "/[^/]*$";`